# Using Repo with Msysgit

Tags: android, msysgit, repository

When following the [Android Open Source Project instructions on installing repo](http://source.android.com/download/using-repo) for use with `Git`, after running the `repo init` command, I run into this error:

> /c/Users/Andrew Rabon/bin/repo: line
>   23: exec: python: not found

I've downloaded repo and put it in `~/bin` like it says, and I've installed `Python`. I wonder what the issue could be.

For reference, I'm using `msysgit` on `Windows Vista`, I understand `msysgit` is limited, but I hope it can at least pull the android source.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a VirtualBox vm with Ubuntu installed. Followed the directions on the source code site and then zipped up the source and copied it over via file share to my windows machine. It's a bulky solution but it's the most straightforward as you don't have to deal with cryptic scripting issues.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you could make msysgit and repo work with some tweaking,

In particular, I think there is an advantage in using Cygwin. It seems to have superior handling of case sensistive file names. This might be irrelevant for the main Android code base, but I know for a fact that it is necessary for the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build Android on Windows. However, you should be able to use repo to pull the source code. I've done this. I imagine you must be using Cygwin. You'll need Python 2.4 (according to [Get Source](http://source.android.com/download#TOC-Other-Linux)) and make sure you don't have any other Python installations on Windows or Cygwin that are overriding it. Check your version using the python interactive shell.

Comment: I'm running Python 2.6 and using msysgit, not Cygwin.

Comment: Try uninstalling Python 2.6 and installing 2.4. I've never tried without Cygwin but I don't think the Python version is negotiable in this case.